# BTOUCH error Bl1001 - do not know how to make a trapoline

Tags: ios, xamarin, cross-platform, static-libraries, wrapper

I am trying to create an iOS binding library to wrap [Kxmovie](https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie). I followed all the instructions in the [Xamarin bindings library walkthrough](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/) and got as far as trying to build the library. However, it fails with the following error;

`Error BI1001: bgen: Do not know how to make a trampoline for IKVM.Reflection.Reader.ParameterInfoImpl (BI1001) (KxmovieBinding)`

Does anyone know what this means or how to fix it?